# Perl File::Find Undocumented Globals

Tags: perl, file, directory, find

[$File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) is a powerful way for traversing a directory tree.

I came across the need to determine (inside the `wanted` function) the top directory from which the recursive search started. [This perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) mentions `$File::Find::topdir` which appears to contains exactly what I needed. So, the particular script I was writing now works.

However, I was curious is there more documentation on this and the other globals mentioned in the same paragraph:

```
$File::Find::topdir
$File::Find::topdev
$File::Find::topino
$File::Find::topmode
$File::Find::topnlink
$File::Find::fullname
$File::Find::prune
```

Or alternatively, could you guys comment on any of these globals if you have used it in your own script-writing ventures.

Comment: I often use fullname (when gathering dirnames/filenames to use outside of the find() call). I sometimes use prune. I don't think I have ever used the others.

Answer (score 1):

If the globals are not documented, they are not intended for public use and you better refrain from using it.

The top* variables seem to be some of the usual meta-data for a file, as returned by the stats() system call. (device, inode, mode (i.e. access rights), number of links)

Comment: Well, they are sort of documented, as @Lex is linking to the official perl documentation.  They're just documented poorly.

Comment: @dsolimano - agreed. On non-unix (file)systems, some of them will also have nonsensical or default values like 0777 for top directories that happen to live in a FAT32, or so I think.

Comment: @dsolimano - agreed also. I'm not exactly a Perl hacker. The reason I found these is because they were in the official perl doc. However, the doc does imply that you should probably not use them directly. This is only implied however, and not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

*$File::Find::prune* is documented, and is very useful. It's like *-prune* option of Unix's *find* command, one sets it to say "don't descend into this directory".

File::Find's POD also documents *fullname* rather well:

- When "follow" or "follow_fast" are in effect, there is also a `$File::Find::fullname`. .... There is a variable `$File::Find::fullname` which holds the absolute pathname of the file with all symbolic links resolved. If the link is a dangling symbolic link, then fullname will be set to "undef".

As for the others- Way back in the early 90's, before Perl5 came along with its handy lexical variables, objects, and closures (and before CPAN), perl shipped with File::Find's precursor "find.pl" - and hence all the package variables that File::Find still uses. For some reason the "top" variables were left in that poorly documented state.

When calling `find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search)`, the modules sets `$File::Find::topdir` to each directory in `@directories_to_search` as it goes through them. The other `top`* variables relate to the attributes of that "top-level" directory.